# function to save JS object not working

Tags: javascript, function, object

I made a HTML project called Customer with some text boxes where can I enter some text and a button called save.Now I want to create a function in JavaScript to save a new contact object.

I tried this:

```
 function SaveContact() {
        var list = [];
        var firstName = document.getElementById("first_name");
        var lastName = document.getElementById("last_name");
        var phoneN = document.getElementById("phone");
        var emailN = document.getElementById("email");
        var birthDay = document.getElementById("birth_day");
        var birthMonth = document.getElementById("birth_month");
        var birthYear = document.getElementById("birth_year");
        list.push({ firstName, lastName, phoneN, emailN, birthDay, birthMonth, birthYear });
        return list;
```

But it doesn't change anything. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What isn't working? What errors do you get? Also, your function is missing a closing `}`.

Comment: @Nero Does my answer help? If so, please accept. If not, feedback please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the following line:

```
list.push({ firstName, lastName, phoneN, emailN, birthDay, birthMonth, birthYear });
```

is that you're only saving values. In JS, you need both values and *keys*. Therefore, you would need to change it to:

```
list.push({ "firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName, "phoneN": phoneN, "emailN": emailN, "birthDay": birthDay, "birthMonth":birthMonth, "birthYear":birthYear });
```

**EDIT**

You say you want to create an *object* but you want to store them as an array. To store them as an array (an object with keys as their indeces), just remove the `{` and `}` in the `push()` line.

However, I think it would be easier to just create an object, like so:

```
function SaveContact() {
    return {
        "firstName": document.getElementById("first_name"),
        "lastName": document.getElementById("last_name"),
        "phoneN": document.getElementById("phone"),
        "emailN": document.getElementById("email"),
        "birthDay": document.getElementById("birth_day"),
        "birthMonth": document.getElementById("birth_month"),
        "birthYear": document.getElementById("birth_year")
    };
}
```

This one-statement function simply creates and returns an [object literal](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/javascript-loops-arrays-and-objects/tracking-data-using-objects/the-object-literal), rather than assigning the values to variables and then putting them into an array/object.

But if you really do want an array, just replace the `{` and `}` with `[` and `]` and remove the keys. This will get you the output you are currently trying to achieve with your program.

Answer (score 0):

Push does not need the `{ ... }` around the elements:

```
array.push(item1, item2, ..., itemX)
```

(from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp))

Also, note that you are storing DOM Elements in the the `list`. You probably need their values and not the elements but it depends on what you try to do...

EDIT - after seeing Jonathan's answer

Alternatively you can do:

```
obj = {}
obj.name = document.getElementById("first_name")
// ... more fields
list.push(obj)
```